# BigQuery/Sql cross join question: exclude from a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I got 2 tables:

[image]

One player id can engage with different features. One can engage any number of features in a month.

What I want to achieve is to have the table produced below:i want to have a non-engaging table that will have all features that are not engaged by a player id.

[image]

```
WITH feature_table as (select distinct
Month,
Feature
From Feature_list),

engaged_player as(
select
'Y' Engaged_YN,
Month, 
Engaged_Feature
FROM ga_data
),

select
from engaged_player 
cross join ?????



)
```

What I have thought is to probably use cross join first.

Comment: please do not use images to present your sample data - rather provide it in text so we can use it to help you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your sample data, try this approach:

```
SELECT 
    'N' AS Engaged_YN,
    gd.Month, 
    gd.Player_ID,
    fl.Feature AS Not_Engaged_Feature
FROM mydataset.ga_data gd
CROSS JOIN mydataset.Feature_list fl
WHERE fl.Feature != gd.Engaged_Feature
ORDER BY Player_ID, Not_Engaged_Feature
```

Output:

[image]